# ASP.Net refresh page sends e-mail again

Tags: asp.net, session, refresh

I've got a page that sends an e-mail to me when someone submits a form and if the user refreshes the page it re-sends the e-mail which is obviously not ideal.

The only way I know of stopping this happening is by using a `Session` and saying

```
If Not Session("blah") = "Y" Then
    'Send e-mail and set Session
End If
```

I'm trying not to use Sessions if I can help it so I just wondered if there was a way to not send the e-mail again if the user refreshes but without `Sessions` or redirecting to another page?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the **[Post-Redirect-Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) approach**, very common in web applications. Many argue that you should not really return content from a POST - just a "success/fail". GETs should return content, so the POST should issue a redirect to GET another page.

```
//handle postback & send email
Response.Redirect("~/feedback.aspx");
```

Comment: +1 for the mention of the Post-Redirect-Get approach (even if it's not what OP wants). Sticking to web best practices and patterns is never a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

If the email is sent on **postback**, just redirect to another page (or the same page). As long as you don't stay on the same page, refreshing will stop sending duplicate postbacks.

Comment: I don't want to redirect the user to a different page

Comment: @Jamie just because you don't "want" to doesn't mean it's not the accepted practice for approaching this problem.

Comment: @Rex  - but it does mean that he's discounted it as the solution for him (which is specified in the body of his question).

Comment: @Joel sometimes all it takes is a better perspective on the problem and a "discounted solution" comes back into play. Play "5 whys" when someone says "we can't do x" without an explanation.

Comment: So redirect to the same page. That beats putting stuff in the session just to denote that a page has already been submitted. In my opinion anyway.

Comment: @Rex M - agreed, which is why I +1'd your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Tyr calling Response.Redirect("YourPage.aspx") to the same page when you're done sending the email.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ViewState of the page instead. Add a `SentMail` boolean property to your page and set it to true when the email is sent. Then you can check `If Not SentMail Then SendMail()`.

```
Public Property SentMail() As Boolean
    Get
        If ViewState("SentMail") IsNot Nothing Then
            Return Convert.ToBoolean(ViewState("SentMail"))
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value as Boolean)
        ViewState("SentMail") = value
    End Set
End Property
```

**Edit:** One thing you can do is perform a check for `If Not IsPostBack` in the `Page_Load` event of the page and initialize the property to false. Then the only event that should set the property to True would be the method that actually performs the sending of the mail:

```
Protected Sub btnSendMail_Click(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as EventArgs) Handles btnSendMail.Click
    If Not SentMail Then
        ' Code to do the sending
        SentMail = True
    End If
End Sub
```

You could make it a little more advanced even so that the page could still be usable beyond just sending the email if you needed by coupling other non-viewstate flags to it like `SentEmailThisPostBack` so that the some sort of reset on this value could be performed according to a set of business rules or even adjust the UI to all user input to perform the reset.

Comment: downvoter - please feel free to comment. It was worth the cost of 1 rep, what's the price of a few more keystrokes?

Comment: @Joel: I hate anonymous downvoting too.

Comment: @Tundey - eh, my thinking is if you have an opinion then own it. I don't even mind that it's anonymous, just that it's not backed up with a reason.

Comment: @Joel this seems as tho it would work but I have a few postbacks on my page so this is getting set before the e-mail gets sent - is there a way I can incorporate your idea still?

Comment: @Jamie Taylor - I have some ideas, but they're involved. I'll post an edit.

Comment: @Joel I've tried implementing your change but it seems to think that the `SentMail = False` so it sends the e-mail

Comment: @Jamie Taylor - be sure that the initialization of the property is not being called on subsequent postbacks. If the only thing that can change the property is the method that sends the mail, then it should register true immediately after sending.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem is

let say i have a function

```
private void btn_delete_click(object Sender, System.EvenArgs e)
{
//logic to perform on button click


// In order to reflect the changes on the current page write


Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), false);
}
```

Now click F5 ............button event will not be fired

Hope it will help u.

Answer (score 0):

You could try forcing the page to expire.

http://www.netnewsgroups.net/aspnet/t275-page-caching-help-needed.aspx